# Is stationary data required when fitting an AR model in Skforecast

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, sklearn-pandas, autoregressive-models

I'm using [Skforecast](https://skforecast.org/0.10.1/index.html) in a project to estimate an AR(p) model. I'm struggling to find out if the data I input to the model needs to be stationarity (de-trended) or if the package handles this?

```py
# Create and fit model
fa_bl = ForecasterAutoreg(regressor = LinearRegression(), lags = 1)
fa_bl.fit(y = Y_data) # Does Y_data need to be stationary?
```

The documentation of the [fit](https://skforecast.org/0.10.1/api/forecasterautoreg#skforecast.ForecasterAutoreg.ForecasterAutoreg.ForecasterAutoreg.fit) method simply states:

> Training time series.